# Nested permalink without dummy parent page

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls

I want a permalink `example.com/foo/bar` without plugins.

So I create the `bar` page using [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/). I'm supposed to set the `post_parent` argument to the ID of the `foo` page.

But I don't want to create a dummy page `foo`.

Can I do this without dummy intermediate pages?

Comment: Not unless you change your permalink structure (categories in permalink, etc.)

Comment: @kero I'm not sure what you mean... how should I change my permalink structure?

Comment: Ah sorry, I was thinking about posts not pages